# Timestamp format match

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, datetime

I wrote this bit of code for converting string to Timestamp:

```
String timeStamp = "2012-04-13 09:00:30";

    try{

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        java.util.Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(timeStamp);
        System.out.println(parsedDate.toString());
        java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(timestamp.toString());           

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

The output i am getting is :

```
2012-04-13 09:00:30.0
```

But i want the output to be:

```
2012-04-13 09:00:30
```

i.e. i dont need the .0 at the end

Please suggest

Thanks,

Comment: why don't you just convert from one to the other? Doesn't just this help you? You can convert from timestamp to date, and the other way around... 
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());

if this isn't enought, can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of format() is always going to be a String.  What exactly are you looking for here?

The ".0" you are complaining about is only there in the string representation of the object.  When it gets inserted into the database, it's a timestamp, not a string.  (You may or may not see extra decimals when you query the database directly; it depends on how you write our SQL.)

Comment: Hi, At the db side, the datatype is timestamp and i will be performing an insert query for this timestamp. According to you, because of the string representaion i am getting that extra ".0". So if i use the code which i wrote in my first post while starting this thread and then perform a insert of the timestamp, then it should work right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `format()` method of `SimpleDateFormat`

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    //parsing string to date
    java.util.Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(timeStamp);
    //invoking toString() method which has its fixed format output
    System.out.println(parsedDate.toString());
```

Now use

```
    System.out.println(sdf.format(parsedDate));
```

Comment: As i said, i need the final convertion in timestamp format but using format, the return type is string. Please suggest how to convert into java.sql.timestamp.

Comment: you have converted correctly, but when you print instance of timestamp its toString method gets executed which has this second part involved

Answer (score 0):

Use your sdf again like this

```
 System.out.println(sdf.format(parsedDate));
```

Comment: hi, forget about the syso. I need to convert the string into timestamp and insert the same into the db. if i use format then the return type is string, not a timestamp